# How to extract Symbolic coefficient of TRANSFER FUNCTION in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

How to extract coefficient in symbolic math **MATLAB**.

eg, i have transfer function like

```
H(S) = (a*S^2 + b*S^ + a*c*S + d*a) / (S^3 + b*c*S^2 + d*S^1 + a*d)
```

I want to get coefficient of 'S' term in H(s) as vector array  like

```
num = [a b a*c d*a]
den = [1 b*c d a*d]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can apply [`numden`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/numden.html) to extract the numerator and the denominator polynomical expression:

```
[numexpr, denexpr] = numden(sym(H))  %// 'sym' makes sure that H is symbolic
```

and then you can extract the symbolic coefficients of `S` by using the [`coeffs`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/coeffs.html) command (remember to apply [`expand`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/expand.html) on each expression first to obtain their polynomial forms).

However, note that `coeffs` returns only the non-zero coefficients. To overcome this issue, I suggest the following:

```
%// Extract numerator coefficients
[numcoef, numpow] = coeffs(expand(numexpr), S);
num = rot90(sym(sym2poly(sum(numpow))), 2);
num(num ~= 0) = coeffs(expand(numexpr), S);

%// Extract denominator coefficients
[dencoef, denpow] = coeffs(expand(denexpr), S);
den = rot90(sym(sym2poly(sum(denpow))), 2);
den(den ~= 0) = coeffs(expand(denexpr), S);
```

P.S: you can also apply [`sym2polys` tool](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/5805-sym2polys) from the MATLAB Exchange on `numexpr` and `denexpr` instead.

Also note that it is more common for the last elements in the coefficient vectors to be associated with the highest powers of `S`, so the result of this solution will be in reverse order to what you have described in your question.

#### Example

```
%// Create symbolic function
syms a b S
H = b * S / (a + S^2)
[numexpr, denexpr] = numden(sym(H));

%// Extract numerator coefficients
[numcoef, numpow] = coeffs(expand(numexpr), S);
num = rot90(sym(sym2poly(sum(numpow))), 2);
num(num ~= 0) = coeffs(expand(numexpr), S);

%// Extract denominator coefficients
[dencoef, denpow] = coeffs(expand(denexpr), S);
den = rot90(sym(sym2poly(sum(denpow))), 2);
den(den ~= 0) = coeffs(expand(denexpr), S);
```

The result is:

```
num =
    [0, b]

den =
    [a, 0, 1]
```

Comment: Thanks alot Eitan for reply... When i use these codes in my actual problem i.e. S(Z1, z) =(Z1*z + Z1)/((Z1 - 25)*z + Z1 + 25); extracting wrt 'z', using code:           syms Z1 z
S(Z1, z) =(Z1*z + Z1)/((Z1 - 25)*z + Z1 + 25);
[numexpr, denexpr] = numden(S);
num = coeffs(numexpr, z)
den = coeffs(numexpr, z)
 Results are--->
num =
 
[ Z1, Z1]
 
 
den =
 
[ Z1, Z1]. Here, den is wrong coz den should be [Z1-25 Z1+25]..

Comment: @Shafqat You did `den = coeffs(numexpr, z)` by mistake instead of `den = coeffs(denexpr, z)`.

Comment: Yup my mistake...Thanks 4 help...:)